# Http Response issues after updating Libraries

Tags: android, httpresponse, google-api-java-client

The following piece of code is throwing a error after i updated to the latest google client apis

```
 catch (IOException e) {
                if (e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
                    HttpResponse response = ((HttpResponseException) e)
                            .getResponse();//The error is here
                    int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
```

At getResponse it throws an error `The method getResponse() is undefined for the type HttpResponseException`
I have tried rolling back to the previous versions of the api but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method was [removed in version 1.10](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0-beta/index.html) of the [Google HTTP Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/).

The exception now has its own [`getStatusCode()`](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.11.0-beta/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException.html#getStatusCode%28%29) method.

Comment: yes found it after wasting a few hours looking for the solution! Thanks again @Jan.